# Querying jar entries in an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

In my OSGi bundle (an eclipse plugin) I can query class entries at certain paths using something like:

```
bundle.findEntries("<class_directory>/<package_name_as_url>/", "*.class", true)
```

For example, if my classes are in the `bin` directory in my bundle, and I want to find all classes in the package `mypackage`, then I could write the path as the string "/bin/mypackage/", producing  this:

```
bundle.findEntries("/bin/mypackage/", "*.class", true)
```

However, I have not managed to do the same when the classes are packaged in a jar inside my bundle. For example, if the jar is `myJar.jar` inside the folder 'lib', how I could query all the classes in it? I tried with these alternatives without any success:

```
bundle.findEntries("/lib/myJar.jar!/", "*.class", true)
bundle.findEntries("/lib/myJar.jar/", "*.class", true)
```

If using strings for writing the paths will not work for resources inside JARs, then how I could query the entries in my bundle that are children of a given resource URL, instead of using a plain string like "/bin/mypackage/" or "/lib/myJar.jar!/" as shown in the examples above? (such URL points to the JAR I need to query).

I know I can use:

```
JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) resolvedURL.getContent();
```

and then

```
jarFile.entries()
```

to get the entries in a Jar, but I am not happy with this solution since: 1) I would like to find a generic way to ask for bundle resources independently if they are in a JAR or not (not funny polluting the code with if conditions). 2) With that solution I cannot automatically filter the resources using a pattern, like "*.class".

Thanks in advance for any help or feedback!

**UPDATE:**

Apparently there is not a simple/efficient way to do this (!) - though I would love to be wrong about that -. I found here a discussion about how to convert a URL in an IPath:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/88506/#page_top

(in the discussion they suggest to use `Platform.asLocalURL().getPath()`, that happens to be deprecated by now, I tried with the equivalent `FileLocator.toFileURL().getPath` instead)

Once you have the `IPath` you could use `FileLocator.findEntries(bundle, path)` to get the children entries from the URL. The problem of this approach is that apparently if the resource you need to query is inside a jar (as in my case), Eclipse will copy it somewhere in your operative system. 
In addition of this being a potential bottleneck for your application, `FileLocator.findEntries(bundle, path)` will fail given that the path is not anymore a real path of the bundle, but the path of a cached directory somewhere in the OS.

I am surprised there is not a direct way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to use the new [`BundleWiring.listResources`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html#listResources%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. This method will search the bundle classpath including jar files for resources such as `.class` files.

Comment: thanks for the answer @BJ. I tried it but still I need to provide a path in the listResources method, and I have the same problems than in my original question: how to find the entries (resources) contained in a specific Jar only.

Comment: Why on earth do you need to look at only the entries in a specific JAR on the Bundle-ClassPath? It seems you really would just want to know all of the *.class resources, in order, along the complete Bundle-ClassPath without regard which Bundle-ClassPath entry they come from.

Comment: Hi @BJ, I was trying to extend the Reflections framework from Google in order to make it work when used in Eclipse plugins depending on external jar libraries. Trying to keep a long story short: for this task I need to create a kind of directory structure for the different jars that conform my Bundle.